# what's the use of lag? when using it do I have to lag my dependent variable or is it only the independent variable?

Tags: regression

I am confused about the usage of lags. I have a problem on multicollinearity and someone propose that I should use lag or conduct a first difference on my model.

***My method of estimation is a simple OLS regression with a time series sample size of 28. When I conduct VIF to test for multicollinearity, I found that my variables have very high multicollinearity issue as one of it has a vif of 204.
To remedy for it, I tried to log-transformed my model but high multicollinearity issue still exists.

Then upon searching the net I found that one of the solution is to lag transformed it but I was confused on how to interpret it.

I am contemplating whether to drop one of my variables but as much as possible i tried to avoid it...so I was finding some ways to resolve this issue.

I also don't know how to regress lags. Like do I have to do it this way:
loggini = logvar1(t) + logvar1(t-1) +logvar2(t) + logvar2(t-1)... logvar6(t) + logvar6(t-1)?
or should I remove the logvar1(t) and just use logvar1(t-1)?

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question?  What problem are you trying to solve? What data do you use? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Using log transformations and lagged features are two separate techniques that could be combined together.

In linear models, when regressors ${x_1, x_2..x_n}$ have multicollinearity one possible affect is estimators having high variance. 
When using log-transformations the fitted model can learn non-linear interactions between regressions and target($y$). When a model has the ability to learn non-linear interactions its possible the multicollinearity affect on estimators variance decreases.

In time series data there are good reasons to believe that both regressors and target are highly correlated(linearly) with their corresponding lagged values - $Abs(corr(x^1_i,x^1_{i-1}))..., Abs(corr(y_1, y_{i-1}))$ are high.
If including lagged values as regressors:
$y_t = \gamma * y_{t-1} +\alpha_1*x^1_t + .. + \beta_1 * x^1_{t-1}+..$
Its common that post fit analysis will reveal $y_{t-1}$ to explain most of the variance.

One method 'de-correlating' lagged features is modeling the differences, I.E:
$z_t = y_t - y_{t-1}$
$w^1_t = x^1_t - x^1_{t-1}$
...
$z_t = \theta_1 * w^1_t + \theta_2*w^2_t + ..$

If lagged regressors $(w^1, w^2, ...)$ show multicollinearity, it might makes sense to include non linear relationships using the log-transformed model(on the lagged regressors).

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you. :) however, how should I interpret Lag values?

Comment: Depends on the model but in general terms: If feature one will change in a(units/percent) then Y will change in b(units/percent).

Answer (score 0):

I quote [the cheat sheet to scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html): if you have 28 data points, get more data.

And statistical tests will be almost worthless with that few data.

If you still want to train a model, I would resolve to very basic models like

- $y \left( x \right) = ax^{2} + bx + c$
- $y \left( x \right) = a \sin \left( bx + c \right)$
- $y \left(x\right) = a \exp \left( bx + c\right)$
- $y \left( t_{i} \right) = a_{1} y \left( t_{i-1}\right) + a_{2} y \left( t_{i-2}\right) + a_{3} y \left( t_{i-3}\right)$

The last model contains lagged variables, you might modify this model by using the log or exponential or sine or something, however, as stated above: with 28 data points, you have to accept, that your model will be poor.

Comment: thank you. Sadly, I only have annual time series data of 28 years.